# Is there a way to add Google Calendar notifications to the indicator message applet?

Tags: indicator, calendar, google-calendar, messaging-menu

Is there a way to have Google Calendar notifications through the message indicator applet *without* using Evolution? Something similar perhaps to "Gmailwatcher"?

**Or**

Is there a way to integrate Google Calendar with reminders into the calendar in ubuntu *without* evolution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli -> "gcalcli is a Python application that allows you to access your Google Calendar(s) from a command line. It's easy to get your agenda, search for events, add new events, delete events, edit events, and even import those annoying ICS/vCal invites from Microsoft Exchange and/or other sources. Additionally, gcalcli can be used as a reminder service and execute any application you want when an event is coming up." -> you can get it output and import to notification area by some scripting

Comment: You can try gcal-notifier-kotlin-gtk: https://github.com/nikitabobko/gcal-notifier-kotlin-gtk it doesn't have evolution as dependency

Answer (score 5):

You can try typing this in a terminal:

```
/usr/lib/evolution-webcal/evolution-webcal ICAL_PRIVATE_ADDRESS
```

(where `ICAL_PRIVATE_ADDRESS` is the [image: ICAL] Private URL of the Google Calendar you want to add)

It only opens a dialog to confirm you want to add this calendar without opening the whole Evolution window, nor the first-run dialog which forces you to add your e-mail account even if you don't intend to use it.

This works with the Gnome 2 calendar applet and I guess it works also for natty's calendar indicator, as it is based on Evolution's calendars. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you, I found just out that once everything is setup in evolution, you don't need evolution anymore and the calendar applet still works with google calendar.

Comment: Yes, that's right. :)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find anything pre-made to do what you ask.

It should be easy enough to program something using python-gdata and python-pyosd, I'd say this would be a good project for an amateur computer programmer getting into some of these technologies.

Of course if you get in touch with an independent developer (like me), we'd be happy to exchange code for money too. Never underestimate paying for things to be made.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't code yourself (and you don't have the cash for Martin ;), you could start a project on launchpad, and once you get some traction from other interested users/developers, work on the actual code (either with your direct collaboration, or with you as project leader).

It is a good way to give back to the community, and to help broaden the available software. You could probably use the code from gmail-watcher or a similar application as a start.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You'll have to use Evolution, but you can program something yourself if you're well-versed in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I found a **Google Calendar Indicator** from [ppa:atareao/test](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/test) but it need "python-gdata 2.0.14" that is not available in Natty repos. (*I downloaded python-gdata 2.0.14 from [Oneiric packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/all/python-gdata).*)

It also use NotifyOSD to alert about an event and more features.
[image: Indicator menu]

It's not bad; try it, wish you like it :)